# image height fix even in responsive without image stretching

Tags: html, css

i want image height fix exact 300px even in responsive screen without image stretching. While i try `object-fit: cover;`and its work what i want but its only compatible with the very latest browsers. 
Please avoid to stupid answers.

```
.container {
        width:100%;
        height:300px;
}

.container img {
        width:100%;
        height:300px;
        }

 <div class="container">
 <img src="images/bnr1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for:

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; 
}
```

or `max-height: 300px` if you expect (portrait) pictures to run over that size.

If you want be sure nothing crosses over the boundaries of the container, you can do the following:

`.container{
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <body>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
 <style>

 .container {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  <!--scontainer img {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    }
    -->
</style>
<body>

<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<img class="col-md-12" src="url.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: use bootstrap if u --@khasif